# Matching Multiple Dog Breed DropDown Lists with Results Logic

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm totally stuck on this.  I hope some expert here can help me out.

I have a page that lists survey results.  The user has to guess the top 3 breeds of a dog. Then, the results are shown. **Important: the user is guessing the TOP 3 breeds of the dog and they can be in any order.**

For example, the user is shown a photo of a dog and underneath the photo is a list of three dropdowns:

```
Dropdown_1    Dropdown_2   Dropdown_3
```

Each of these dropdowns contains the same list of breeds, such as Beagle, German Shepard, Pug, etc.  The user then selects one (and only one) breed for each of the dropdowns.

So, in the example above, the user would select:

```
German Shepard   Beagle   Pug
```

Now, when the answer/response page is displayed, they will see if their guesses match the correct answers.

Obviously, it would be easy to write something like:

```
  If (BreedChoice1 = BreedChoice1Answer And BreedChoice2 = BreedChoice2Answer And BreedChoice3 = BreedChoice3Answer) Or
           (BreedChoice1 = BreedChoice1Answer And BreedChoice2 = BreedChoice3Answer And BreedChoice3 = BreedChoice2Answer) Or
           (BreedChoice1 = BreedChoice2Answer And BreedChoice2 = BreedChoice1Answer And BreedChoice3 = BreedChoice3Answer) Or
           (BreedChoice1 = BreedChoice2Answer And BreedChoice2 = BreedChoice3Answer And BreedChoice3 = BreedChoice1Answer) Or
           (BreedChoice1 = BreedChoice3Answer And BreedChoice2 = BreedChoice1Answer And BreedChoice3 = BreedChoice2Answer) Or
           (BreedChoice1 = BreedChoice3Answer And BreedChoice2 = BreedChoice2Answer And BreedChoice3 = BreedChoice1Answer) Then

Response.Write("You Guessed ALL breeds correctly!")

End If
```

But how would I display message they says: "You guessed two breeds correctly".  And one that says "You guessed one breed correctly"?

Remember that choice 1, 2, and 3 can match the answers 1, 2 and 3 in any order.

Any advice would be appreciated!  Thank you in advance.

-- Chris

Comment: How can 1 dog be three different breeds?  Makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this it would be simplest to use an Intersect method and to section up your code a little differently.

Firstly I would suggest that we put the "answers" into a list rather than keep them as separate variables (since you suggest they can be in any order). Then you should put your submitted answers also into a collection.

You can then do a very simple Intersect to get a collection that contains the elements common to both:

```
List<string> breeds = new List<string>() { "Beagle", "German Shepard", "Pug" };

        List<string> choices = new List<string>() { "Beagle", "Pug", "Greyhound" };

        int correctAnswers = breeds.Intersect(choices).Count();
```

The int "correctAnswers" then tells you how many they got right. (Obviously if you are using something more complicated than a string, such as a custom "Breed" class, for the breeds you could use some Linq to check the breed name property).
You could then use a neat bit of string interpolation (the $ sign in front of the string declaration) to get your result message:

```
$"Congratulations, you guessed {correctAnswers} breeds correctly!";
```

Hope his helps!

Comment: Paul, thank you! This is EXACTLY what I was looking for and solved the issue.  I really appreciate your help. I'm marking this answer as best and all the best to you sir!